# Cannot find GDAL retile

Tags: gdal, osgeo

I cannot find GDAL retile Python script. It says the "'gdal_retile.py' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file".

Do I have a raster driver down somewhere that's not currently installed?

Comment: How did you installed GDAL?

Comment: It may be located in a folder like C:\OSGeo4W\apps\Python39\Scripts. Also, you may need to add C:\OSGeo4W\apps\Python39 to your PATH environment variable.

Answer (score 0):

Going on the form of the error message I'm going to guess you are using a windows machine, and that you installed GDAL using OSGEO4W.

You need to add `gdal-python` to your install. Run `setup` and select `Advanced Install`, then open up `libs` and look for `gdal-python` click where it says `skip` until it gives you `3.1.4-3` (or a similar number, it should be the same as the other `gdal-xxxx` entries). Then click next as usual.